# Node client receiving too many hit from node server on single update

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I am new with the node js.
I am using node js with express.

I am create connection on server side via below code.

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  // console.log('A new socket connected with id : '+socket.id);
   socket.on('error',function(e){
      // console.log(e);
   })
   socket.on('disconnect',function(e){
      // console.log( " \n disconnect \n ",e);
   })
   socket.on('UserRoom', function(data){
      var user_id = data.user_id;
      if(socket.adapter.rooms[user_id]===undefined)
      {
          console.log('Hey i am connected to server for User id => '+user_id);
          socket.join(user_id);
      }
      else
      {
          console.log('Hey i am already connected to User id');
      }

     }); 
    socket.on('JoinDraft', function(data) 
    {
       var game_unique_id    =  data.game_unique_id;
       socket.join(game_unique_id);
    });
});
app.post('/game_update', function(req, res)
{
   var target = true;
   var response = '';
   req.on('data', function (data) {
       response += data;
   });
  req.on('end', function () {
       res.sendStatus(200);
      var result = JSON.parse(response);
      game_update(result);
  });
});
```

function game_update( result )
   {
       var game_unique_id = result ;
       io.to(game_unique_id).emit('game_update', {"game_unique_id":        game_unique_id});
    };

client side code :- for joining room

```
function joinDraft_socket() {
    // console.log(gameObj);
   socket.emit('JoinDraft',{"game_unique_id" : gameObj.game_unique_id});
}
```

for getting node response , we have

```
socket.on('game_update', function(data) {
    if(data.game_unique_id == gameObj.game_unique_id) {
        console.log('Trigger to update ', data);
        isYourPick();        
    }
});
```

Server node emit data single time to any room ( game_unique_id)  then clients are receiving server ping  multiple times.

Please let me know if any one face this kind of issue and how they resolved it.

Below is image of console after single update of server node , client receive multiple hits

[image]

Any help is appreciate ...

Thanks in Advance

Comment: How are you emitting 'game_update' event?

Comment: Thanks for asking, I have updated code